# WPF C# - WindowChrome Resize Overlaping Button

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

I have a window with a WindowChrome object and a UserControl full of buttons

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0,0,0,1" ResizeBorderThickness="2,0,2,2" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<Objects:WindowButtons x:Name="WinButtons" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

I want to have a nice unbordered window while maintaining ease of controlling the size.

### However the resize tool overlaps the buttons so I cannot click on it and I can only click on the bottom left of the button

How can I place the buttons above the resize dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you simply need to add this property to your button:

```
WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
```